# OWIN self static file server multiple routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, katana

I have configured in my Owin a webApi and an static file server to fetch some files that we will need in my app.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)
{
   //Other middlewares and configurations
    ....
   application.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
   {
       RequestPath = new PathString("/myPath1/public"),
       FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(m_FolderPathProvider.myPath1FolderPublic)
   });

       // Attribute routing.
            .....
 }
```

This is working like a charm. What a I need it's to declare another FileServer for another path and another different physical folder. What I'm frightening is if I do it in the same way I will override this one and I will have only one. So how can I declare a second fileserver?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT, you can "mount" different FileSystem paths onto different routes, using the same overload you are already using.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)
{
   //Other middlewares and configurations
    ....
   application.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
   {
       RequestPath = new PathString("/myPath1/public"),
       FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(m_FolderPathProvider.myPath1FolderPublic)
   });

   application.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
   {
       RequestPath = new PathString("/myPath2/public"),
       FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(m_FolderPathProvider.myPath2FolderPublic)
   });

       // Attribute routing.
            .....
 }
```

If you want to have them merged, I don't think it's possible with `UseFileServer`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: nope, you didnt miss something, my question sounds pretty dumb but I tried this approach and didn't worked. Must be something about my general solution because I tried this in a different isolated solution and is working fine. So thank you :)